# Twitter Bootstrap on Symfony2 with NetBeans (Windows)

Tags: windows, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, netbeans, composer-php

When I create a new project with NetBeans, I choose a PHP project and a PHP Application
As sources folder, I choose C:\xampp\htdocs\X and I run as Local Web Site (running on local web server) and as Project Url there is automatically "http:// localhost /X/".
So I go on X->Symfony2->Run Command and I generate a bundle who I call, for example, "xHelloWorldBundle".
When I go on "RUN", opens the page http:// localhost /X/, so Index of/X.
Now, I want to install Twitter Bootstrap because I want to create a Landing Page.

How to install Twitter Bootstrap for Symfony2 on NetBeans?

Comment: Composer component's, Twitter's bower, MopaBootstrapBundle, there are so many ways to do it and they all work with Windows...

Answer (score 2):

First of all install composer (it's the package manager symfony sugests)

[composer installation on windows](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)

Then install the symfony2 framework with composer (it's the recommended way by symfony) and I find it personally a better way then the netbeans installation of symfony2!

[Install symfony2 with composer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#installing-a-symfony2-distribution)

There a few bundles that help integrate twitter bootstrap in symfony

- [MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle#mopabootstrapbundle) -- [Installation guide](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-installation.md)
- [BraincraftedBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle#bcbootstrapbundle) -- [Installation guide](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle#installation)

As an extra tool you could use (as mentioned above) [Bower](http://bower.io/). This is an assets manager for your js, css,...

Here is a guide to [integrate bower in symfony2](http://blog.ronny.lt/blog/2012/11/05/managing-symfony2-web-assets-with-bower/)

I think the tools/bundles should help you to start project with symfony2 and twitter bootstrap!